# How to write an memory efficient code on IOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

This question looks very straight, However I have a situation here, I just need some help how to do it in efficient way. Say for e.g: I have three views View 1, View 2, View 3.

At First, I pushed View 1 from a base view, then View 2 from View 1, then View 3 from View 2. Now View 3 need an object which is holding the information of a user. So here What I done was pass that user object from base one to View 1, and to view 2 and to view 3 while loading all views, Here every view is storing that object as Ivar even though View 1 and 2 don't use that.

I don't think its good to access View 3 directly from base to set the object, Or access base from View 3 to get value, Any idea guys how to handle this kind of situation.

As a beginner, Just I want to clarify this doubts. thanks.

Comment: For that, you will have to go through the whole documentation given by Apple. Go to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf

Comment: @Newbee You may get better answers if you talk about your actual views and objects in concrete terms, instead of completely abstract terms like “view 1” and “view 2” and “an object which is holding the information of a user”.  What does the “base view” show?  What does it let the user do?  What about “view 1”?  Etc.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for your suggestion,I am using ARC, I want to know only how the data transmission should be between views, thats why I didn't mention anything about views(Each view doing nothing simply pushing other views). Anyhow  I will correct it in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use singletons to keep information that you need in different classes/views across the application.

[Follow this good tutorial](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) if you don't know how to implement singletons in Objective C.

Answer (score 5):

If you are passing the same object around all the 3 views, it does not take up any extra memory as only the retain count of that object will be incremented per view. So effectively memory for only one object is accounted.

Comment: It is not the same object, I am pushing every view on certain condition only, Until I push next view, I need an iVar to hold that object and set to next view.

Comment: OK. Even in that case you don't have to worry about the memory take up by that object, because when you set the object from say View1 to iVar of View2, only the retain count of that abject will be incremented and no extra memory will be allocated.

Comment: And regarding the access to the user info object, I think you can have the object instance maintained in the app delegate as mentioned by others.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you are trying to create an object in view 1 and use in view 3.
Suppose that object is Employee Class.
Here is how to use it.

Alloc and init Employee object in view 1.
Override init method of View 2 like

```
-(id)initWith:(Employee*)emp
{
     temEmp=emp;
}
```

Similarly override View 3 init.

Since you alloc and init object only once, same object is shared by all three views.
You don't waste memory

Answer (score 1):

you may define the user info as a class UserInfo.Then you can code sth as bellow in UserInfo.m:

```
static UserInfo *sharedUserInfo_ = nil;
+ (UserInfo*)sharedUserInfo{
  if(sharedUserInfo_ == nil){
  sharedUserInfo_ = [[UserInfo alloc] init];
}
return sharedUserInfo_;  
}
```

Comment: So I have to access Base from View 3. Is it a good approach to do? It leads to cyclic dependency I guess.

Comment: Yes,but you can set Base View as a attribute of View 3 and set its property to assign just like delegate.

Comment: Can you please share any sample code for that?

Comment: see some code about delegate

Answer (score 1):

Create that user object in AppDelegate.Create appdelegate reference in view3.

```
 in view3.h
     AppDelegate *appdelegate;


 in view3.m
 -(void)viewDidLoad
   {
   appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication SharedApplication]delegate];

   appdelegate.userobj=......

   }
```

use that object directly in view3